# What can we do with Propositional Logic?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, applications

I've studied a bit of propositional logic and first order logic, I know that propositional logic is sound and complete ($\Gamma \vdash \gamma$ if and only if $\Gamma \vDash \gamma$), I know what maximally consistent sets are, etc.

But I never understood how propositional logic could be used for anything, as in, what are some things we can represent with propositional formulas as to actually apply all the theoretical background.

Comment: [Related](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/1002/real-world-applications-of-logic).

Comment: Glancing through that question it  seems that the answers adress more basic concepts, I'm looking for 'applications' that use a bit of more advanced prop. Logic concepts.

Answer (score 1):

For a well-known example of application (think at your cell-phone) see : [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) and [Logic gates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate).

From the point of view of mathematical logic, *propositional calculus* is a "laboratory" where we can develop and learn the "machinery" - consistency, semantics, soundness, completeness, compactness - to be used with more complex languages and theories.

Comment: I've thought about  your mathematical point of view, but propositional logic seems so weak in terms of the things you can represent with it, even first order logic is insufficient sometimes. Could you expand a bit on the mathematical applications of prop. logic?